# How to set the start position for a video using AxShockwaveFlash (revised)

Tags: c#, winforms, axshockwaveflash

Revised question with added detail...

I'm trying to use AxShockwaveFlash to play a youtube video and start it at a specific location. This is within a C# winforms app. I have the basics. I can successfully start and stop the video. I cannot, however, figure out how to set the position and *start at a specific time* within the video. What property or method needs to be called to do this?

Here's what I have so far:

```
 AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash mFlashPlayer;
 ...
 mFlashPlayer.Movie = @"http://www.youtube.com/v/9O9HfafzBPE?version=3&hl=ru_RU";
 mFlashPlayer.Play();
```

I've tried setting various properties and calling various methods, but I'm just guessing. For example, I tried calling

```
 mFlashPlayer.GotoFrame(200);
```

and it did nothing. Seems so simple, I'm starting to wonder if I'm encountering a bug. ?

I also tried using the standard form when using a web browser, which is to encode it directly in the url. For example, the following did not work either:

```
 mFlashPlayer.Movie = @"http ...blah... #t=77s";
 mFlashPlayer.Play();
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**ANSWER**

Apparently, I'm not authorized to post an answer, so I'm editing the question and adding it here...

**Got it!** The magic trick is to set the 'start' parameter in the url that you provide to the Movie property or the LoadMovie() method.

```
Embedded AS3 player:
http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3&start=NUMBER_SECONDS

Chromeless AS3 player:
http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?video_id=VIDEO_ID&version=3&start=NUMBER_SECONDS
```

Replace VIDEO_ID and NUMBER_SECONDS with the desired values.

**Example:**

```
mFlashPlayer.Movie = @"http://www.youtube.com/v/1ZKz2KW87Y4?version=3&start=100";
```

I found the required info here: 
 [https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters](http://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

That was one of the more frustrating hunts for info that I've been on in a while. Hope this post saves other folks the headaches.

Comment: Look here: http://forums.adobe.com/message/5000800. "Seeking a specific time may not be possible. You can only seek to a keyframe in video. That goes for all progressive video of any kind in any language. If a language allows you to seek without a keyframe it's going back to the previous keyframe and rendering all frames to create the timestamp you're seeking to. The only exception to this rule for FLV is a Flash Media Server (FMS). You may want to seek to 3:59 but Flash will seek to the nearest keyframe (forward or backwards) so don't expect it to do that unless a keyframe exists at 3:59."